# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

I am reading lot of XML files in java, and converting them to JSON and writing them back to file system. Total size of XML folder is around 100Gb and size of single XML file can go to around 100MB. Size of JVM memory is set 512Mb. Here is the loop for reading and writing files :

```
  for(int i=0; i<fileNames.size(); i++) {

  try{
    File f = new File(File.separator+fileNames.get(i));


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    String line;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line.trim());
    }


    String jsonData = XML.toJSONObject(sb.toString()).toString(0);

    String outputFilename = fileNames.get(i).split("\\.")[0]+".json";

    Path jsonFilePath = new Path(jsonPath+File.separator+outputFilename);

    FSDataOutputStream out = fileSystem.create(jsonFilePath);
    out.writeChars(jsonData);
    byte[] b = jsonData.getBytes("UTF-8");

    out.close();
    br.close();

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    double executionTime = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0;

    System.out.println("Input file : "+fileNames.get(i)+" - "+(double)(f.length()/1000) + " kb");
    System.out.println("Output file : "+outputFilename+" - "+(double)(b.length/1000) + " kb"+" in "+executionTime + " seconds");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}catch (JSONException je) {
    System.out.println(je.toString());
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }
```

After running for some time this program throws :  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, if I increase JVM memory to -Xmx1024 program runs very slow and java process consumes lot of memory. Because I am creating file, stringbuilder and bufferedreader in for loop these are in memory and they are not garbage collected. How can I make this code work. Thanks

Comment: You can try use several threads running parallel. Each thread works on different file so they won't interfere each other. This of course require larger memory usage

Comment: Can you check if the problem is a single file?  Moving the `System.out.println()` for the input file to before processing should tell which file is last when the OOM occurs; then modifying the code to only run on that one file will tell if it's a single-file issue or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code carefully, no memory leaks are apparent, so it seems likely the problem is caused by a single input file that is just too large to process.

Setting the JVM heap size to 1024 could be running very slowly if it's more than the available memory on the server, as that would lead to swapping, which is disk I/O and very slow.

The only way to eliminate a problem caused by a single input file, using the same hardware, is to change the processing in some way that uses less memory.  For example, using an xml-to-json conversion tool that uses less memory, or finding a way to split the XML into pieces and put it back together; that's not trivial though.

You could move to larger hardware.  Make sure to use a 64-bit O/S and 64-bit version of java if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are some things you can try

1. It is possible to manually invoke the garbage collector, System.gc() if I remember correctly.
2. You can use a profiler (as the one provided with Netbeans) to see where memory leaks.
3. You can also look into weak references/phantom references, but my knowledge on those is low.

Comment: It's unlikely that forcing garbage collection will affect an out-of-memory exception.  Garbage collection will run before the out-of-memory exception is thrown.  However, it's not impossible for it to help.